# React Module Not Found, I've never had this problem

Tags: reactjs

I can't import my module, it keeps giving me the same error, I have looked into what I may have done wrong but I dont see it. Everything works for my other components (They are all in the same folder "./[Folder]") except this component and it's being passed the exact same way.

[Module Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM3l5.jpg)

**ManageTreeComponent.jsx**

```
import React from "./react";
function DisplayListItems(){
  
    return(
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
  
  export default DisplayListItems;
```

**LoginApp.jsx**

```
import DisplayListItems from "./ManageTreeComponent.jsx";

function Login() {

  return <div className="container">
    <DisplayListItems /> 
  </div>
}

export default Login;
```

**index.js**

```
import Login from "./components/Login/LoginApp";
ReactDOM.render(<div>
<Login />
</div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your import `react` statement is wrong in `ManageTreeComponent.jsx`, make sure your import looks like this:

```
import React from "react"; // without period and /
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using .jsx file use .js file

ManageTreeComponent.js

```
import React from "react"; // need to import like this

function DisplayListItems(){

    return(
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    );
  }
  export default DisplayListItems
```

LoginApp.js

```
import DisplayListItems from "./ManageTreeComponent";

function Login() {

  return (
       <div className="container">
         <DisplayListItems /> 
     </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

index.js

```
import Login from "./components/Login/LoginApp";
ReactDOM.render(<div>
<Login />
</div>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Okay, but why not use jsx? I don't quite follow you there.